# Accessing Data from SQL using DataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis-8

My DB in C# which is in dll is like this

```
    static SqlConnection cnn;
    static SqlDataReader reader;
    public string StorePass;
    public string  pass;
    byte[] tmpSource;
    byte[] tmpHash;
    public int  user;
    //static ArrayList list;
    static string connect = @"Server=.;database=Intranet;Integrated Security=true";

    public static void open()
    {
        cnn = new SqlConnection();
        cnn.ConnectionString = connect;
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
        } //open connection
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Source);

            Console.WriteLine("unable to open");
        }
    }
    public bool login(int usr, string pass)
    {
        user = usr;
        this.pass = pass;
        string temppass;
        tmpSource = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass);
        tmpHash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(tmpSource);
        temppass = ByteArrayToString(tmpHash);
        DB.open();
        StorePass = DB.retrievePass(user);
        bool bEqual = false;
        bEqual = String.Equals(temppass, StorePass, StringComparison.Ordinal);

        if (bEqual)
        {

            return true; 
        }

    }
    static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] arrInput)
    {
        int i;
        StringBuilder sOutput = new StringBuilder(arrInput.Length);
        for (i = 0; i < arrInput.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            sOutput.Append(arrInput[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sOutput.ToString();
    }

    private static string retrievePass(int user)
    {
        using (cnn)
        {
            string pass = "";
            string table = "Login_Table";
            string strSQL = string.Format("Select * From {0} where UID = '{1}'", table, user);
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn);
            cnn.Open();
            reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            /*while (reader.Read())
            {
                pass = reader["Hashed_Password"].ToString();
            }*/
            try
            {
                reader.Read();
                pass = reader["Hashed_Password"].ToString();
                reader.Close();
                return pass;

            }
            catch
            {
                reader.Close();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

My aspx.cs from website from which i call the above methods to access is

```
    DB ob;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ob = new DB();
    DB.open();
}
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        int id = int.Parse(Login1.UserName);

        string pass = Login1.Password;
        if (ob.login(id, pass))
        {
            Session["user"] = ob;
            this.Session["UserName"] = Login1.UserName;

            Response.Redirect("Post_View.aspx");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

The above code works well simulated from visual studio. But when deployed in IIS 8 it shows error Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0'. Please help me in this as other codes also written in similar shows error when Deployed in IIS. Whether i have to change my code ? Thanks in Advance

My Stack Trace

```
      Server Error in '/Test' Application.

     Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0'.

   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web     request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0'.

  Source Error: 


 Line 80:                 string strSQL = string.Format("Select * From {0} where UID = '{1}'", table, user);
 Line 81:                 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn);
 Line 82:                 cnn.Open();
 Line 83:                 reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
 Line 84:                 /*while (reader.Read())

 Source File: e:\Demo\Intranet_DB\Intranet_DB\DB.cs    Line: 82 

 Stack Trace: 


 [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0'.]
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +578
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +88
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6322807
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +258
 Intranet_DB.DB.retrievePass(Int32 user) in e:\Demo\Intranet_DB\Intranet_DB\DB.cs:82
 Intranet_DB.DB.login(Int32 usr, String pass) in    e:\Demo\Intranet_DB\Intranet_DB\DB.cs:51
  _Default.Login1_Authenticate(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\Default.aspx.cs:38
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +152
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +124
    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +70
    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing 'IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0' has access to the sql database?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I cant get you? We have to change settings anything in IIS server to access particular database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your connection string. You're using current user to log in to the database and the user that is running your application pool in IIS (IIS APPPOOL.NET v2.0) doesn't have access to the database.

You should either:

1. Change the connection string and specify a different user.
2. or, Change the user running the application pool.

Comment: U mean that I should specify different server in my connection String?

Comment: No, rather add a `User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;` to specify your username and password.

Comment: What's your connection string? (Put xxx instead of username and password)

Comment: static string connect = @"Server=.;database=Intranet;Integrated Security=true;User ID=xxxx;Password=yyyy"; the userid and password is for SQLServer Login

Comment: Remove `Integrated Security=true;` as it makes it use current Windows user

Comment: After Removing Integrated Security I get the Error As "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open"

Comment: You're opening an already open connection. Remove unnecessary `Open()`. But this is really a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Your own Application Pool by using the exact version of .Net framework.
2. Modify your connection string by using User Name and Password, Do not use it with windows authentication.

Comment: Could please explain how to create own Application Pool?

Comment: Remove Integrated Security tag from your connection string. It is creating conflict for SQL Server.

Comment: After Removing Integrated Security I get the Error As "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open"

Comment: This problem does not belong to connection string. Plz check your code. You have to close your open connection before you call Connection.Open() function. So simply call Cnnection.Close() function before executing the command.